# Programmatically access list of live Spark nodes

Tags: apache-spark

I've implemented a custom data layer on Spark that has Spark node persisting some data locally and announcing their persistence of data to the Spark master. This works great by running some custom code on each Spark node and master that we've written, but now I'd like to implement a replication protocol across my cluster. What I'd like to build is that once the master gets a message from a node saying it's persisted data, that the master can randomly select two other nodes and have them persist the same data.

I've been digging through the docs but I don't see an obvious way of the SparkContext giving me a list of live nodes. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isnt a public API for doing this. However, you could use the Developer API SparkListener (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener). You can create a custom SparkListener class and add it to the SparkContext as

```
   sc.addSparkListener(yourListener)
```

The system will class the onBlockManagerAdded and onBlockManagerRemoved when a BlockManager gets added or removed, and from the BlockManager's ID, I believe you can get the URL of the nodes running the Spark live executors (which run BlockManagers).

I agree that this is a little hacky. :)